# How can I return value of input inside a td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to loop through an html table and returning the `td` values. However, one of my `td` includes an input and I am having a hard time returning the input's value. Here is my table:

```
<table style="width:35%" class="table" id="category_markups_table">
  {{#each context.category_0}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{category_name}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="1.0" class="form-control" name="{{category_name}}" value="{{markup}}"></td>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Here is my code to loop through the table:

```
$("#category_markups_table").find('tr').not(':first').each(function (i, el) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td')
        var obj = {};
        obj = {
            id: $tds.eq(2).text(),
            markup: $tds.eq(1).input.val() //this is where i need help
        }

        console.log(obj);
});
```

Specifically, the `markup: $tds.eq(1).input.val()` is where I need help. As it stands, that line returns `val() of input undefined`. Can someone help?

Comment: `$tds.eq(1).input.val()` – what do you imagine `input` to be here in that line? When you wanted to select the table cells, you did not just write `td` somewhere, connected to other bits of JS code by dots – so why are you trying that now with the input field…?

Comment: try `markup: $tds.eq(1).find('input').val()`

Comment: Could you post representative HTML of what you're using instead of whatever templating language that is?

Comment: @CBroe `input` contains a number that I am trying to return. It can be updated so I put it in an `input` field

Comment: that's perfect, thank you so much!! @MaxZuber

Comment: I did not ask you why you used an input field; I asked what made you think that `input` _in JavaScript/jQuery_ was a valid way to select an input element? You knew how it worked for table cell elements a few lines before …